# Create a new column only if values differ

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

My dataframe looks like this :

```
pd.DataFrame([["t1","d2","e3","r4"],
         ["t1","d2","e2","r4"],
         ["t1","d2","e1","r4"]],columns=["a","b","c","d"])
```

and I want:

```
pd.DataFrame([["t1","d2","e3","r4","e1","e2"]],
columns=["a","b","c","d","c1","c2"])
```

ie I have only 1 column that values differs and I want to create a new dataframe with columns added when new values are observed. Is there an easy way to do this ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### Edit: To generalize for any single non-unique column:

```
Ucols = df.columns[(df.nunique() == 1)].tolist()
df_out = df.set_index(Ucols).set_index(df.groupby(Ucols).cumcount(), append=True).unstack()
df_out.columns = [f'{i}{j}' if j != 0 else f'{i}' for i,j in df_out.columns]
print(df_out.reset_index())
```

Output:

```
    a   b   d   c  c1  c2
0  t1  d2  r4  e3  e2  e1
```

#### Original Answer

Use:

```
df_out = df.set_index(['a','b','d',df.groupby(['a','b','d']).cumcount()]).unstack()

df_out.columns = [f'{i}{j}' if j != 0 else f'{i}' for i,j in df_out.columns]

df_out.reset_index()
```

Output:

```
    a   b   d   c  c1  c2
0  t1  d2  r4  e3  e2  e1
```

Comment: It looks to me that this doesn't generalize. I mean you know already that column `c` has more values.

Comment: Updated solution to handle not knowing 'c' has more than one value.   Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

You can use a dictionary comprehension. For consistency, I've included integer labeling on all columns.

```
res = pd.DataFrame({f'{col}{idx}': val for col in df for idx, val in \
                    enumerate(df[col].unique(), 1)}, index=[0])

print(res)

   a1  b1  c1  c2  c3  d1
0  t1  d2  e3  e2  e1  r4
```

An alternative to `df[col].unique()` is `df[col].drop_duplicates()`, though the latter may incur an overhead for iterating a `pd.Series` object versus `np.ndarray`.

Comment: Here you can `unique` instead of `drop_duplicates()`

Comment: @user32185, Good point, have included that alternative. I believe it should be more efficient as `unique` returns an array, i.e. no `pd.Series` overhead.

Comment: I'm curious to know if it's possible to use a comprehension with a `for` inside the else in order to obtain the OP requested output. See my answer as reference.

Comment: @user32185, You can probably do something like `d = {1: ''}; f'{col}{d.get(idx, idx)}'`, since you can use `dict.get` within an f-string. So if it's a 1 it'll just be an empty string, otherwise return the integer.

Answer (score 4):

Not as beautiful as Scott answer but the logic you are looking for is:

```
out = pd.DataFrame()
for col in df.columns:
    values =df[col].unique()
    if len(values)==1:
        out[col]=values
    else:
        for i,value in enumerate(values):
            out[col+str(i+1)]= value
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `drop_duplicates`

```
s=df.reset_index().melt('index').drop_duplicates(['variable','value'],keep='first')


pd.DataFrame([s.value.values.tolist()],columns=s['variable']+s['index'].astype(str))
Out[1151]: 
   a0  b0  c0  c1  c2  d0
0  t1  d2  e3  e2  e1  r4
```